# Predicting Past End of Dataset with RNN in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset spanning hundreds of values regarding temperature. Obviously, in meteorology, it is helpful to predict what future values will be based on the past.

I have the following stateful model, built in Keras:

```
look_back = 1
model.add(LSTM(32, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
for i in range(10):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=4, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX, batch_size=batch_size)
```

I have successfully been able to train and test the model on my dataset to reasonable results, however am struggling to comprehend what is required to predict the next, say, 20 points in the dataset. Obviously, these 20 points are outside of the dataset, and they have yet to "occur".

I would appreciate anything that would be of help; I feel like I am missing some simple functionality in Keras.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel like I am missing some simple functionality in Keras.

You have all you need right there. To obtain predictions on new data you have to use `model.predict()` again, but on the *desired range*. This depends on how your data looks.

Lets assume your timeseries `trainX` had events with `x` ranging from `[0,100]`.

Then to predict the next 20 events you want to call `predict()` on values `101` to `120`, something like:

```
futureData = np.array(range(101,121)) #[101,102,...,120]
futurePred = model.predict(futureData)
```

Again, this depends on how your "next 20" events look. If you bin size were instead 0.1 (100, 100.1, 100.2,...) you should evaluate the prediction accordingly.

You may also like to check [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) page where they give examples and explain more about Timeseries in Keras with RNNs, if you are interested.